# Attempted import error: 'HelpBlock' is not exported from 'react-bootstrap'

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, form-control

I'm creating a Login form in react to check the login parameters, but when I run the code I'm thrown this exception:

`Attempted import error: 'HelpBlock' is not exported from 'react-bootstrap'`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Row, FormGroup, FormControl, Button, HelpBlock } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { isEmail, isEmpty, isLength, isContainWhiteSpace } from './validator';

class Login extends Component {

    render() {
        const { errors, formSubmitted } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="Login">
                <Row>
                    <form onSubmit={this.login}>
                        <FormGroup controlId="email" validationState={ formSubmitted ? (errors.email ? 'error' : 'success') : null }>
                            <FormControl type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                            {errors.email && <HelpBlock>{errors.email}</HelpBlock>}
                        </FormGroup>
                    </form>
                </Row>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: react-bootstrap does not contain a component named `HelpBlock`, where did you see that? React-bootsrap docs: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components

Comment: @MartinHorváth how can i change it?

Comment: According to the forms documentation of react-bootstrap, you'll need to use `Form.Text` to display a message: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/forms/

Comment: ok thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

React bootstrap does not have a `HelpBlock` component.

[image]

I propose to show you errors in an `Alert` component, like so:

```js
return (
  <div className="Login">
    <Row>
      <form onSubmit={this.login}>

        <FormGroup controlId="email" validationState={formSubmitted ? (errors.email ? 'error' : 'success') : null}>
          {errors.email && <span className="text-danger">{errors.email}</span>}
          <FormControl type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />

        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup controlId="password" validationState={formSubmitted ? (errors.password ? 'error' : 'success') : null}>
          {errors.password && <span className="text-danger">{errors.password}</span>}
          <FormControl type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </FormGroup>
        <Button type="submit" bsStyle="primary">Sign-In</Button>
      </form>
    </Row>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Ok @Titulum, Thnks a lot

Comment: [Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the <Form.Text> component available in react-bootstrap instead which is imported on the Form component. HelpBlock has been removed after Bootstrap 3(react-bootstrap v1) to my knowledge.